# Vue cli to heroku with express return H10 code and cannot find module express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, vue-cli-3

I tried to deploy a Vue Cli app to Heroku and the build was success but when I open the url in the browser I got **Application Error**. I checked the error log and found this `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`. I wonder why express won't work since I already installed it using `npm install express --save`.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/'));
app.get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running smoothly on port ' + port);
});
```

**Package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

**Error log**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just found the fix and this is important.

Install express in `dependency` not in `devDependency` or else Heroku won't install the package.

```
npm install express --save-prod
```